# How to implement a image list control with SWT?

Tags: swt, controls, imagelist, clistctrl

Does anybody have any idea on how to easily implement a image list(like the windows explorer with medium icons) control with swt? it seems like that it could be done easily with CListCtrl in c++ on windows, but does not seem to be easy with swt? any hints are appreciated!

Comment: have you checked this http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/gallery/gallery.php

Comment: what I want is to implement it just using swt or jface, but don't like to rely on other projects, thank you for this information anyway

Comment: Here is another [`Gallery`](http://sharemedia.free.fr/swtgallery_home.php). Since they are all open source, it might be worth looking at the code to figure out how you could do it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Up to me, you need to create your own widget (check e.g. http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11489/Custom-SWT-List-Box) and add composite items to your custom list.

Answer (score 0):

If vertical-only scrolling is enough, I suggest you rely on a single column `TableViewer`. This is what I did in a project where I needed a gallery-like window allowing the user to pick a graphical component based on displayed thumbnails.

You just need to implement the proper `TableLabelProvider.getColumnImage` and return the desired thumbnail corresponding to your list entry.

That gives a pretty decent list-like rendering.

In addition, `TableViewer` API is very well documented.